# Creating a new rails database record from an external script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, hash, nested

I'm trying to send a POST request from an external Ruby script to a Rails app via `HTTP#post_form`. The request is made to the `create` action (i.e. the URI is `http://server/controller`).

If I encode a single parameter into the request, everything is fine:

```
HTTP::post_form(uri, { :my_param => "value" })
```

Though I do have to explicitly pull out `my_param` from `params` manually, in the controller. This seems inefficient, and breaks creating a new record from within the app itself (because that parameter is not there). I'm consequently trying to make my script pose as Rails itself, passing the appropriate data as the controller would expect it, e.g.

```
HTTP::post_form(uri, { :object => { :my_param => "value" } })
```

However, this doesn't work. `post_form` seems to be escaping my hash into something different, i.e.

```
{ "object" => [\"my_param\", \"value\"] }
```

Which obviously doesn't do the same thing. Am I missing something obvious in the way I'm passing the data? Or can I not achieve what I'm after (creating a new record from outside the app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One straightforward way might be to simply imitate how Rails formats its parameters, like this:

```
params = { :my_param => "value", ... }
params = Hash[params.map { |key,value| ["object[#{key}]",value] } ]

HTTP::post_form(uri, params)
```

**Edit:** Well, look at that, I looked around a bit and found that Rails actually gives you a method to do the same thing using their own mechanism:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
...
HTTP::post(uri, parameters.to_param)
```

The `to_param` method will treat Arrays correctly, and everything else too. Notice that in this case you want to use `HTTP::post`, not `post_form`, since the parameters are already converted to a string.

Comment: Excellent, that works thanks! However it seems to break down when the values are arrays. You don't happen to know how to handle that case do you?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about post_form but the natural solution for me would be to use an ActiveResource object.

ActiveResource is available to ruby as well as to Rails. you use it just like you use a model only it posts and gets using XML
There is a Railscast on how this works here

http://railscasts.com/episodes/94-activeresource-basics

http://railscasts.com/episodes/95-more-on-activeresource

I think you'll find that this is a better fit for your requirements than post_form but as I say, I'm not familiar with post_form.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that. I'm trying to keep the dependencies down, but I agree that it looks like exactly what I want :)

Comment: After a bit of playing around, the only disadvantage of this approach is that it doesn't seem to currently support ActiveRecord associations (e.g. has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: You can can support related tables but you have to create your own xml template to include the records you need. I'll try and find time later to update my answer.